# Matching raster regional extent with vector region in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion, region

In Grass GIS, I am able to import bathymetry .tif raster data however the region coordinates are not in lat/lon formar and therefore, do not overlay with my vector points which are in lat/lon format. Is there a way to convert the raster extent so that both layers show in my computational region? I have already tried to create a new location with the correct EPSG code and then import both layers, however it has been unsuccessful.

Comment: So you have two data sets with different coordinate systems? When you mention the new location and importing, do you mean that you: created two locations (one for each data set), and then used r.proj to import the raster into the lat long location?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a raster and a vector in different coordinate systems (i.e., one in lat/lon and the other not lat/lon), you will need to set up two GRASS Locations. One Location with the coordinate system of the raster and the other for the vector. Import the raster and vector into their respective Locations. Then run `r.proj` from the vector Location to reproject the raster into the vector coordinate system, or run `v.proj` from the raster Location to reproject the vector.

Comment: BTW: In recent GRASS GIS 7 we added r.import (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.import.html) and v.import (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.import.html) which quite simplify this procedure.